# how to get correct format from xlsx - to interpret floating point number formated as text

Tags: c#, openxml

i am aware of the floating point inaccurrancy, this is just how to get the correct text FORMAT!! by openxml from the xlsx and show the value like excel does. I am not able to edit the excel file and change the format or something like that, because of some reasons.

while working with [numbers formated as numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvSxn.jpg) everything runs fine

[formatted as text or general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxOA9.jpg), the number 0.813 is saved as 0.812999.., excel shows it correct!, but via openxml i can't get the used format (0.000), anyone an idea to get the format?

maybe this is a standard format, not saved and choosen by other values?

Comment: why not parse the string to `int` and then save it as a number? If it is a number, why save it as a `string` in the first place?

Comment: this is part of a preview, there for, this is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I am using the ugly solution to get rid of this ..

if the cellFormat NumberFormatId is 2 I try to parse the value to double and then to string with two decimals

`double.Parse(displayedValue).ToString("0.00");`

not my desired solution, but for the moment this works .. of course also with all other unit tests